# Elisp: Added one key-binding to dired-mode and lost basic dired functionality

Tags: dired, key-bindings

I wanted an alternative to the awful `C-^` shortcut for moving up one directory so I added the following to `init` file:

```
 (defun dc/dired-mode-keys ()
   "User defined keys for dired mode."
   (interactive)
   (local-set-key (kbd "s-m" 'dired-up-directory)))
 (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'dc/dired-mode-keys)
```

However, when I open Emacs with this code enabled (i.e., uncommented in the init file), I lose basic dired functionality.  For example, when I press `a` to open a directory (in the same buffer), I get the following error in the mini-buffer.

```
Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 1), 2
```

I've confirmed that `s-m` is not a native key-binding in `dired-mode` (I believe very few if any `super` key combos are natively bound), and I'm pretty sure my code doesn't unbind any of the native key-bindings in dired-mode.

What am I doing wrong in the function above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "wrong number of arguments" error comes from the `kbd` inside `dc/dired-mode-keys`. Your parentheses are nested incorrectly, so you pass 2 arguments to `kbd`, but it expects only 1.

Try this instead:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "s-m") 'dired-up-directory)
```